# Unable to update Ubuntu 10.10 installed in MacBook Pro with dual boot

Tags: grub2, updates, macbook

So, this is my problem:

I was able to install Ubuntu 11.10 in dual boot in my MacBook Pro 5.1 with rEFIt. I had to do it twice because first time I installed GRUB in /sda instad of in /sda3. Anyways, it wouldn't work: after choosing Ubuntu in rEFIt I got the balck screen with the white cursor.

Someone told me to try with an earlier version, so I installed Ubuntu 10.10. It works fine, but when I update to 11.04 I get the same problem: it won't boot Ubuntu anymore.

Any idea of what can I do to update Ubuntu? It looks like a problem with GRUB but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update to version it 11.04 you will not succeed because each older Ubuntu can only be updated to the latest version and it is now 11.10. If you took a lot programs and plugins, go to ubuntu.com and download version of 11.04 (by the official Ubuntu site you can download the upcoming (12.04), current (11.10) or a previous version (11.04)). This is made through Mac OSX because you would rather install Ubuntu 11.04 installer ask if you delete Ubuntu 10.10 (on a single computer can have only one Ubuntu). I would recommend you still can download Ubuntu 11.10, so you dial between 11.04 and Ubuntu Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You are saying that since I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 I can't update the common way, rigth? So i have to download the intall cd of Ubuntu 11.10, then boot into my Ubuntu 10.10 Ubuntu and install it? Or do I have to download first 11.04?

What do I do when it asks me about GRUB?

Comment: NVM I was able to update now

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did not use rEFIt to fix the partition table after installing Ubuntu.  Look at the section "Fix the partition tables" section of this [help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation).

Comment: Actually I followed those instructions. After installing Ubuntu 11.10 I tried to fix the tables with rEFIt, but it didn't let me. I tried fixing the tables by booting into the LiveCD and downloading gsync, but I wasn't able to save gsync in mnt/root, so I couldn't do it.

Any ideas of how to fix the tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok.  Don't bother with the LiveCD.  Go into OS X and use the terminal to follow the directions in [post #185](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11215214&postcount=185).  That worked for me, so hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: I actually tied that too, but it seemed to not recognize I had installed gdisk. Right now ubuntu 11.10 is working, I just have the problem that rEFIt shows 2 Linux icons. Not a big deal, although if you now how to fix it I would really appreciate ;)

Comment: That's strange you were not able to run gdisk... What happens if you try booting off the other "Linux" partition?  Also, you mentioned above that this other Linux partition is on "HD", does that mean "Macintosh HD"?  Do you also have an Apple icon to boot into OS X?  Also, it would be helpful to go into Disk Utility in OS X and see the list of partitions (their file system types and size).  This will help you fix the partition tables (which is probably what you need to do anyway to fix this issue).

Comment: I have 3 icons: Apple from HD, Linux from HD and Linux from Partition 3. Both Linux icons work fine and log into the same system (user, folders, everything the same). When I run the list of partitions that's what I see, although I'll check again. Thanks!

Comment: So yes, 3 partitions: Mac, LinuxSwap and Linux. No need to sync tables according to rEFIt, but gsync not found. That's all I can say!

Comment: Hi.  There are some things confusing me here.  You are supposed to have a BIOS partition (it will be very small, e.g. 1MB).  This is separate from your main Linux partition and swap partition.  If you don't have one, something is seriously wrong.  You should see it in Disk Utility (technically there is also another EFI partition which is used by your MBP to start up, but Disk Utility will wisely hide that from you).  Note that what rEFIt shows you is not all your partitions; it will only show you at most 4, due to the way it sets things up.

Comment: rEFIt will also keep telling you misleading info as you have to run gdisk first.  If you installed it, you should be able to run `sudo gdisk`.  You can't run gdisk as a normal user; that's why you need `sudo` and then type in your password.

Comment: Disk Utility shows 4 partitions: 200mb as boot volume, 173gb as the Mac partition, 1023mb named "disk0S2" (this is the linux Swamp) and 59gb named "disk0S3" which is the Ubuntu partition. I'm going to boot into Ubuntu and see what it says. About `sudo gdisk` I run it from MacOS terminal, right?

Comment: Disk Utility in Ubuntu shows 3 partitions (it doesn't show the 200mb one). Gparted shows the 4 partitions, and when I installed Ubuntu the installation tool showed the free space that you say.

Comment: Yes, you run it from the terminal in OS X.  So follow the [directions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11215214&postcount=185) up to and including step 8.  Your configuration is different, so you won't be selecting three partitions as he does, but only two [your Mac partition and your Linux main partition, the "root partition" (not boot or swap)].  Once you do this, you reboot and at the refit menu, sync the partition tables.  Then after (assuming no error messages!), you should be able to reboot and see only two boot icons.

Comment: Some additional comments: Since you know the the sizes of everything, hopefully you won't have any problems identifying the different partitions in following those instructions.  You should start with `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0` as he does (it's extremely unlikely your EFI partition is not disk0, but if you see anything bizarre that doesn't match your info so far, you should quit and come back here).  Also, I don't know if this is to be concerned about but 200MB is extremely large for a BIOS boot partition... probably no point in worrying about it now.  199MB lost megabytes  won't matter, I hope.

Comment: So, I downloaded gdisk and installed it (just double click on the .pkg file). Then in terminal I worte `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`, and after writting my password i get `dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap` No idea what to do next.

Comment: Unfortunately, a google search strongly suggests that this is due to differences between Leopard and Snow Leopard.  It works on the latter...but perhaps not on the former as you are finding :(  Given the length of this comment thread, I suggest starting another question with the all the info you have so far.  You'll get more eyes as it is a new question.  I think I've run out of ideas :(  But I'll try again later (have to rush off).

Comment: Thanks C S, we have gone as far as we could!!! hahaha. Can you mark the thread closed, since the original problem was solved? I'm new around and don't know how to do that.